# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I have set the visibilty for button as "gone" but now when i want to set button visible , Getting following error while trying to set visibility for button

```
    @Bind(R.id.btn1)
    Button btn1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hifragment_main, container, false);

      if(1==1) 
        {
            btn1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: What due you mean by `if(1==1)` ? and where initializing `btn1`?

Comment: it is just a true value say if condition occurs true just for reference here but i am using different equation.

Comment: what is `if(1==1) ` ?

Comment: want to show button if condition occurs true else it will be hidden

Comment: It will Always be true... **There nothing like if the condition is true. IT IS BY DEFAULT TRUE.** post your `hifragment_main`.

Comment: Are you using **Butter Knife**  ? or any other please explain.

Comment: Yes i am using Butter Knife

Comment: @Marsh Which version of **Butter knife** you are using ? can you show your `Gradle` ?

Comment: Make sure you're using the exact Layout the button is located in

Answer (score 6):

you didn't initialize you button, please initialize it as below,

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hifragment_main, container, false);
btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
```

Comment: using  @Bind(R.id.btn1)
    Button btn1;Even after initializing getting same error

Comment: can you please post your xml also ?

Comment: <LinearLayout style="@style/vFragmentMain">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn1"
                    style="@style/btnFragmentMain"
                    android:text="AA1"
                    android:visibility = "gone"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

Comment: are you inflating proper layout.. please check it once otherwise it must not be null. and please try to initialize button as my answer just for testing purpose.. and let me know if it is working or not ?

Comment: if I run the same condition somewhere else say on other button click then it works but i dont want to use other button to show or hide button

Comment: please try to initialize button as my answer just for testing purpose.. and let me know if it is working or not ? your button is not initialize before your are setting visibility.

Comment: btnstockdistrict=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnstockdistrict1); Here findviewbyid gives an error cannot found , if i use getview().findviewbyid then it returns following error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: dear, find your view by btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn1); after inflating your layout and it will work. here view  is your view that you are inflating please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your button object.

```
btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_btn_id);
```

Then you can check `if (btn1 != null)`

Comment: if it return null then what to do

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.hifragment_main, container, false);
        btn =view.findViewById(R.id.btn) // this line is important

        btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return view;
    }
//it's work for me .
`
```